# How to get a `NSURL` of the document directory?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following code:

```
+(NSURL*) getRecordingDirectory {
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:documentsDirectory]; //<-- nil
    return url;
}
```

The line `NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:documentsDirectory];` Doesn't seem to work. `url` remains `nil` after the line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a file URL to get the location of a resource on the file system.

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory]
```

You can also use `NSFileManager` to get the same URL.

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentsUrl = [arr firstObject];
```